# Run Python Script on computer boot

Tags: startup, python

How can I create a python script that runs when the computer boots? I know to get it to run on login I can turn it into an app and add it to a as a startup item in settings, but I need it to run once the computer boots.

How can I make a python script run when the computer is turned on?

I am running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1 and Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a plist like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.username.scriptname</string>    
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
    <string>/path/to/script.py</string>
  </array>    
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>    
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/com.username.scriptname.err</string>    
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/com.username.scriptname.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Just make sure you replace the /path/to/script.py accordingly and then save it to your desktop. Then open up terminal and type `sudo chown root:wheel /path/to/plistfile` it will prompt for password type it in in and when you are typing it it won't give you any visual feedback then press enter. Then type `sudo chmod 644 /path/to/.plistfile`. Then just `sudo mv ...` the plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ or /Library/LaunchAgents/ and finally `sudo launchctl load ...` the plist and your script will run.

And if you have any problem comment below and also tell me the OS your Mac is running.

Comment: If you'd like a more visual way to do this, soma-zones' [Launch Control](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) offers a great interface for `launchd`. It's got a free trial and costs only $10. (I'm not affiliated with them in any way. Just love the app.)